# Converting dataframe with WKT column to spatial dataframe in ArcGIS API for Python

Tags: python, shapely, well-known-text, arcgis-python-api

I am querying a data set from an Oracle spatial server with the geometry field in a WKT format, and I am running into issues trying to convert it to a spatial dataframe using the ArcGIS API. Going through the API documentation, there's no direct way to import a WKT, nor do I find that in example projects. The `GeoAccessor.from_df()` function has a *geometry_column* parameter but this only seems to be expecting the geometry in the ESRI format (although there's no mention of this on the [docs](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.features.toc.html#geoaccessor)).

I'm using the API instead of GeoPandas because after I'm done massaging the data, I need to post it to an ArcGIS online page and the API seems to handle this pretty easily. The only similar use case I found [on the ESRI forums](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-api-for-python-questions/arcgis-python-api-set-geometry-column-of-spatially/td-p/858974), converts the WKT into a shapely object, then uses the `Geometry.from_shapely()` function, but this keeps returning a '_HASSHAPELY' is not defined error. The only requirements are that it results in a spatial dataframe and doesn't require ArcPy. This seems too obvious and I feel like I'm missing something.

This is when I tried it directly

```
import arcgis
from arcgis.geometry import Geometry
from arcgis.features import GeoAccessor, GeoSeriesAccessor
import pandas as pd
import shapely
from shapely import wkt

print(
    f'Arcgis: {arcgis.__version__}  \n'
    f'Shapely: {shapely.__version__}  \n'
    f'Pandas: {pd.__version__}'
)

>>> Arcgis: 2.0.0, Shapely: 1.7.1, Pandas: 1.3.4

# conn = connection string goes here
df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM DB', con=conn)
df

>>>   objectid                                     shape_wkt
0     83081       POLYGON ((2650551.5177502 224562.792018803, 26...
1     25643       POLYGON ((2646974.1601797 228173.696717298, 26...
2     13084       POLYGON ((2483098.44031584 209641.4424441, 248...
3     83086       POLYGON ((2600620.00982339 205015.101437584, 2...
4     22395       POLYGON ((2589453.06485915 204928.628606869, 2...
..         ...                                                ...

sdf = GeoAccessor.from_df(df,
                          address_column=None,
                          geometry_column='shape_wkt')
sdf

>>> objectid shape_wkt
0   83081       {}
1   25643       {}
2   13084       {}
3   83086       {}
4   22395       {}
..         ...                                                ...
```

And this is when I tried it the longer hacky way

```
# conn = connection string goes here
df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM DB', con=conn)
df

>>>   objectid                                     shape_wkt
0     83081       POLYGON ((2650551.5177502 224562.792018803, 26...
1     25643       POLYGON ((2646974.1601797 228173.696717298, 26...
2     13084       POLYGON ((2483098.44031584 209641.4424441, 248...
3     83086       POLYGON ((2600620.00982339 205015.101437584, 2...
4     22395       POLYGON ((2589453.06485915 204928.628606869, 2...
..         ...                                                ...

df['shapely_geom'] = df.shape_wkt.apply(wkt.loads)
df

>>> objectid                                     shape_wkt                                         shapely_geom
0   83081       POLYGON ((2650551.5177502 224562.792018803, 26...   POLYGON ((2650551.5177502 224562.792018803, 26...
1   25643       POLYGON ((2646974.1601797 228173.696717298, 26...   POLYGON ((2646974.1601797 228173.696717298, 26...
2   13084       POLYGON ((2483098.44031584 209641.4424441, 248...   POLYGON ((2483098.44031584 209641.4424441, 248...
3   83086       POLYGON ((2600620.00982339 205015.101437584, 2...   POLYGON ((2600620.00982339 205015.101437584, 2...
4   22395       POLYGON ((2589453.06485915 204928.628606869, 2...   POLYGON ((2589453.06485915 204928.628606869, 2...
... ... ... ..

type(df.shapely_geom[0])
>>> shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon

df.shapely_geom[0]
>>>
```

[image: shapely_polygon]

```
df['esri_geom'] = df.shapely_geom.apply(Geometry.from_shapely)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-5c763be36efd> in <module>
----> 1 df['esri_geom'] = df.shapely_geom.apply(Geometry.from_shapely)

~\Miniconda3\envs\map_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwargs)
   4355         dtype: float64
   4356         """
-> 4357         return SeriesApply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, kwargs).apply()
   4358 
   4359     def _reduce(

~\Miniconda3\envs\map_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in apply(self)
   1041             return self.apply_str()
   1042 
-> 1043         return self.apply_standard()
   1044 
   1045     def agg(self):

~\Miniconda3\envs\map_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in apply_standard(self)
   1099                     values,
   1100                     f,  # type: ignore[arg-type]
-> 1101                     convert=self.convert_dtype,
   1102                 )
   1103 

~\Miniconda3\envs\map_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

~\Miniconda3\envs\map_env\lib\site-packages\arcgis\geometry\_types.py in from_shapely(cls, shapely_geometry, spatial_reference)
    875 
    876         """
--> 877         if _HASSHAPELY:
    878             gj = shapely_geometry.__geo_interface__
    879             geom_cls = _geojson_type_to_esri_type(gj["type"])

NameError: name '_HASSHAPELY' is not defined
```

The shapely package is obviously imported, the geometry is listed as a shapely geometry, and even browsing through the rows, the polygon will render in a notebook, so no idea why the HASSHAPELY variable would have a not defined error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this issue was reported to the [arcgis-python repo](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-python-api/issues/1173) and has been fixed but not yet released.

As a workaround you may consider rolling the ArcGIS Python package back to `1.9.1` rather than the current `2.0.0` release.

You may also try setting `arcgis.geometry._types._HASSHAPELY = True`.

Comment: Manually installed the 2.0.1 prerelease version and the HASSHAPELY bug has been corrected. Thanks for sharing the issue.